# pyinstaller error with os.Pathlike object

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I wrote a long code that uses pyodbc, pandas, openpyxl, and PyQt5.  Every time I wanted to convert it to a .exe, i had no problem.  Until recently, I wanted to make some updates and then use pyinstaller to make into a .exe. Now I get the following error for the exact same code that previously had no errors.  After one minute of converting to .exe, pyinstaller stops and gives this error.  Again, I made no changes to the code.  This error never happened before and converted to .exe flawlessly.  Now for some reason I get the following error (see last line in bold):

I am using pycharm to execute pyinstaller via a virtual environment in the terminal view. However, even when I try to convert using cmd command prompt, I still get same error.

**TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType**

HERE IS THE TRACEBACK:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\richa\PycharmProjects\newEDAT\venv\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('PyInstaller==3.5.dev0+73dfb3add', 'console_scripts', 'pyinstaller')()
  File "C:\Users\richa\PycharmProjects\newEDAT\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 111, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\Users\richa\PycharmProjects\newEDAT\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 63, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\richa\PycharmProjects\newEDAT\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 844, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "C:\Users\richa\PycharmProjects\newEDAT\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 791, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\richa\PycharmProjects\newEDAT\new_EDAT_116.spec", line 29, in <module>
    console=True )
  File "C:\Users\richa\PycharmProjects\newEDAT\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 424, in __init__
    strip_binaries=self.strip, upx_binaries=self.upx,
  File "C:\Users\richa\PycharmProjects\newEDAT\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 196, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "C:\Users\richa\PycharmProjects\newEDAT\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 158, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "C:\Users\richa\PycharmProjects\newEDAT\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 273, in assemble
    pylib_name = os.path.basename(bindepend.get_python_library_path())
  File "C:\Users\richa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ntpath.py", line 214, in basename
    return split(p)[1]
  File "C:\Users\richa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ntpath.py", line 183, in split
    p = os.fspath(p)
```

Comment: You should copy the whole traceback from the error here

Comment: Just posted it.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try running it outside of the venv

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that using Python IDE and just cmd command prompt.

Comment: Did you upgrade your python version to 3.7 recently? See this https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3942

Comment: I did upgrade.  I changed computers and installed all the latest upgrades to Python and all related modules.   I think that is where the issue is.  And until Pyinstaller is updated, I and others will have this issue.

Comment: It seems you're running it from inside a virtual environment (considering this part of your path newEDAT\venv\). So if you manage to run your script without activating your virtual environment it should work like it worked for others on the link I gave you.

Comment: Thank you. I’ll give it a try.